# Laravel 5.4 AJAX does not work if CSRF_TOKEN is added

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to build a site using laravel 5.4. Trying to get data from the database using ajax. But if i put csrf token inside the ajax call sometimes i get the desired data i want sometimes i don't. But if i don't put csrf token in the ajax call i always get my desired data.

Here is my AJAX code.

```js
 $(function(){
     var checking_html = '<img src="img/loader.gif" />';

     $("#bond").change(function () {
         $('#load').html(checking_html);
         var x = $('#bond').val();

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: "{{ URL::route('bond.list') }}",
             data: {
                 '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                 'x': x
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 if(response[0]['bond_num'] == 400000){
                     response[0]['bond_num']='Premium';
                 }
                 html_output = '';
                 for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                     html_output += '<option value="'+response[i]['publish_date']+'">'+response[i]['publish_date']+' , '+response[0]['bond_num']+' Bond</option>';
                     if(i==0){
                         html_output += '<option value="all">ALL</option>';
                     }
                 }
                 $('#choice').empty().append(html_output);
                 $('#load').html('');
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 alert('Error get data from ajax');
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: *I am trying to build a site using laravel 5.4* Everytime I see this on SO, I wonder why people voluntarily use [EOL and unsupported versions of software](https://endoflife.software/programming-languages/frameworks/laravel) to build **new** software. Please update to at least Laravel 5.5 and preferably 5.6!

Comment: Can you show your blade file? Are you sure `input name='_token'` is defined?

Comment: Yes input name='_token' is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to use CSRF protection in ajax is [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

You should add a `meta` tag in the head of your template.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

After that you can use it to pass the csrf token in the request header like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```